# Javascript how to start script on exact time

Tags: javascript, loops, time, setinterval

1. script will start on exact time (ex: 2015:06:15:00:00)
2. If its on time, it will alert HELLO every 1 second.

setInterval(function () {alert("Hello")}, 1000);

could you please help me how to make this on up?

Comment: I am not against your question, but I curious what would you use this for. I might get cleaver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I'd use the [getTime object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) in JS
2. I believe I have the time set right in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2bxn3fr/5/)

   ```
   var d = new Date();
   var year = d.getFullYear();
   // Month 0 = January | Month 11 = December | so I changed vallues by +one
   var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
   var day = d.getDate();
   var hour = d.getHours();
   var minute = d.getMinutes();
   var second = d.getSeconds();

   var overall = year.toString() + month.toString() + day.toString() + hour.toString() + minute.toString() + second.toString();

   alert(overall);

   var checkDate =  function () {
   if(overall==="20156150000") {
       setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 1000);
       };
   };

   window.setInterval(checkDate(), 1000);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to define a date driven trigger in javascript.

Instead you might register your function from the beginning and check there if the start date is reached.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var startDate = new Date("2015-06-14 12:47");
            window.setInterval(checkDate, 1000);

            function checkDate()
            {
                if (new Date() > startDate)
                    myDate.value = new Date().toLocaleString(); //or do your alert ;)
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="myDate" style="width: 200px" />
    </body>
</html>
```